# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing open3d_pybind: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, importerror, open3d

I see that other users have also run into this issue when using Pycharm, but coundn't find a fix when error with import open3d. I have tried the approaches suggested however, adding to Path did not work (Windows 10). Many thanks for your help!

The error message is:
[image]

I tried adding the following Environment variables to PATH:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution! The issue was multiple versions of Python installed. I deleted Anaconda and any other Python versions. Then reinstalled a 'fresh' version. This solution is further explained here:

How to resolve "ImportError: DLL load failed:" on Python?
[How to resolve "ImportError: DLL load failed:" on Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41365446/how-to-resolve-importerror-dll-load-failed-on-python)

Answer (score 1):

After several tries, the only thing that worked for me was install CUDA (and visual studio before, because demanded by CUDA). I had forgotten that wasn't installed since my reinstallation of windows operating system...