# ImportError from skimage: How do I fix it?

Tags: python, scikit-image

Python throws the following error:

```sh
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\VEERAR~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12200/2758554015.py in <module>
     22 
     23 
---> 24 from skimage.segmentation import clear_border
     25 opening=clear_border(opening)
     26 

c:\users\veerarajzx10r\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\skimage\segmentation\__init__.py in <module>
      1 from ._expand_labels import expand_labels
      2 from .random_walker_segmentation import random_walker
----> 3 from .active_contour_model import active_contour
      4 from ._felzenszwalb import felzenszwalb
      5 from .slic_superpixels import slic

c:\users\veerarajzx10r\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\skimage\segmentation\active_contour_model.py in <module>
      2 from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline
      3 from ..util import img_as_float
----> 4 from ..filters import sobel
      5 
      6 

c:\users\veerarajzx10r\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\skimage\filters\__init__.py in <module>
      2 from ._gaussian import (gaussian, _guess_spatial_dimensions,
      3                         difference_of_gaussians)
----> 4 from .edges import (sobel, sobel_h, sobel_v,
      5                     scharr, scharr_h, scharr_v,
      6                     prewitt, prewitt_h, prewitt_v,

c:\users\veerarajzx10r\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\skimage\filters\edges.py in <module>
     16 from scipy.ndimage import convolve, binary_erosion
     17 
---> 18 from ..restoration.uft import laplacian
     19 
     20 # n-dimensional filter weights

c:\users\veerarajzx10r\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\skimage\restoration\__init__.py in <module>
     11 from .inpaint import inpaint_biharmonic
     12 from .j_invariant import calibrate_denoiser
---> 13 from .rolling_ball import rolling_ball, ball_kernel, ellipsoid_kernel
     14 
     15 

c:\users\veerarajzx10r\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\skimage\restoration\rolling_ball.py in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
      2 
----> 3 from ._rolling_ball_cy import apply_kernel, apply_kernel_nan
      4 
      5 

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _rolling_ball_cy: The specified module could not be found.
```

I believe it has to do with DLL load. I have no idea what it is or how to fix it.

Comment: Have you looked  and tried solutions from this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/4780) on their repo?

Comment: It appears this to be issues with Windows: there are multiple similar questions here in SO: I would recommend installing skimage via `conda` from miniconda as it fixes issues for Windows users. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41365446/how-to-resolve-importerror-dll-load-failed-on-python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58612306/how-to-fix-importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing-win32api

Comment: i did installed using conda but still gotten error