# Cannot import Producer from confluent_kafka

Tags: python, python-3.x, confluent-platform, confluent-kafka-python

I'm using conda environment with python 3.9 and confluent_kafka library (installation by pip install confluent-kafka). I have also installed librdkafka. From pycharm I cannot import:

```
from confluent_kafka import Producer
```

I receive this errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/Projects/Kafka/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from confluent_kafka import Producer
  File "C:\Users\kmode\anaconda3\envs\dataScience\lib\site-packages\confluent_kafka\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from .deserializing_consumer import DeserializingConsumer
  File "C:\Users\kmode\anaconda3\envs\dataScience\lib\site-packages\confluent_kafka\deserializing_consumer.py", line 19, in <module>
    from confluent_kafka.cimpl import Consumer as _ConsumerImpl
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cimpl:
```

Can you help to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reinstalations of anaconda and removing python 3.9 I fixed the issued by using python 3.7. in anaconda environment. As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41365446/how-to-resolve-importerror-dll-load-failed-on-python) the reason is to have version 3.8 and higher, but I don't know how to resolve it exactly on python 3.8 and above.

> If anyone comes across this issue in Python > 3.8 with Windows, dll's
> are only loaded from trusted locations
> https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#ctypes This can be fixed
> by adding the dll path using os.add_dll_directory("PATH_TO_DLL")

Answer (score 0):

## Answer already existing

---

I saw an answer similar to yours (not a duplicate at all, but it solves your problem).
[How to resolve "ImportError: DLL load failed:" on Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41365446/how-to-resolve-importerror-dll-load-failed-on-python)

---

They suggested to uninstall and then reinstall python, and if I understood well it worked.

---

Somebody else installed Anaconda instead, and it worked too.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using Anaconda with Python>=3.8, set your environment variable.

```
set CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_ENABLE=1
```