# from qgis._core import * //ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _core: The specified procedure could not be found//VS Code//Environment conda

Tags: python, pyqt5, dllimport, init, qgis

How do I fix this error? I tried all the solutions given on other pages where similar errors were posted.

My Python version: 3.9.13, Anaconda: 23.1.0, QGIS: 3.28.2, WINDOWS 10 X64

**My error:**

```
PS C:\Users\samudra.nayak\Downloads\qgis-temporal-profile-master> & C:/Users/samudra.nayak/Anaconda3/python.exe c:/Users/samudra.nayak/Downloads/qgis-temporal-profile-master/temporalprofileplugin.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\samudra.nayak\Downloads\qgis-temporal-profile-master\temporalprofileplugin.py", line 43, in <module>
    from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsPointXY, QgsGeometry, QgsWkbTypes
  File "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.2\apps\qgis\python\qgis\core\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from qgis._core import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _core: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

**My environment variables:**

PATH

```
C:\Users\samudra.nayak\Anaconda3;
C:\Users\samudra.nayak\Anaconda3\Library\mingww64\bin;
C:\Users\samudra.nayak\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;
C:\Users\samudra.nayak\Anaconda3\Library\bin;
C:\Users\samudra.nayak\Anaconda3\condabin;
C:\Users\samudra.nayak\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages;
C:\Users\samudra.nayak\Anaconda3\Scripts;
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.2\apps\qgis\bin;
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.2\bin;
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
C:\Users\samudra.nayak\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.2\apps\grass\grass78\lib;
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.2\apps\Qt5\bin;
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.0\apps\Python39\Scripts;
C:\\Users\\samudra.nayak\\Anaconda3\\DLLs;
```

PYTHONPATH

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.2\apps\Python39;
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.2\apps\qgis\python;
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.2\apps\qgis\python\qgis;
```

I need someone to tell me how to setup my environment and IDE to import the `qgis.core` library.

I have tried the following to get the path on the `qgis` python terminal. I pasted the path onto PATH and PYTHONPATH but it just gave more errors.

```
import sys
print (sys.path)
```

I tried these too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67437837/15222441,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/73666691/15222441,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41376679/15222441

Comment: You probably can't mix and match a Conda environment with the Python that's embedded with QGIS...

Comment: I thought so too and tried it with the usual python environment but it gave me the same error. Also I know many others who use conda environment with the python embedded in qgis so I guess it should work on mine too.

Comment: Check [\[SO\]: Can't import dll module in Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59333711/4788546) and some of the referenced *URL*s, or [\[SO\]: PyCharm doesn't recognize installed module (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73363599/4788546). How did you install *QGIS*?

Comment: Maybe you must use the *Python* embedded in *QGIS*? Try creating environments starting with *v3.7*, and see whether there's one that works.